# Getting weird flickering in SFML.NET 2.2 when using views and drawing lots of stuff at the same time

Tags: c#, sfml, sfml.net

I am using SFML.NET 2.2 (just upgraded from 2.1 which also had the same issue) and I got some weird behavior when rendering lots of stuff to the screen. It might also be somewhat related to using several views, I don't really know.

I did search for a solution, but was only finding others having problems with V-sync or clearing twice etc. I checked and I am fully sure that I don't clear the screen twice and I do not have V-sync enabled at the same time as setting framerate limit.

I am making a game, and when just the map is being drawn everything is fine. If i then enable weather particles everything is still fine. If i turn off the weather and toggles the map editor gui it is still fine. But if i have both the weather and editor gui at the same time, each with lots of rendering going on, there is some strange flickering on the screen. It looks like scewed and stretched letters or boxes that flies within the area of some view.

(I can't post images yet)

Please help me, I don't know why this is happening but it is really disturbing and makes the game not-so-funny to play and edit.

Comment: Sounds like a buffering issue, try to find a double buffer method for SFML.NET 2.2

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I found [this link](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/graphics-draw.php#the-drawing-window) in the official documentation which points out that if not doing clear/draw/display in that order just once per "tick" there can be problems due to double buffering. However I checked and I have just one call to Clear and one to Display. Everything in between are rendering calls and SetView.